# How do i make a div/iframe clickable only once

Tags: html

The title says it all : How do i make a div/iframe clickable only once

Im stuck with this for a long time,so I decided to ask for a little help.

Please,if you wanna help,put the whole script in here,not just a part of it so I get confused.

Thank you.

Comment: If you (OP) want to help out, then post *your* code.

Comment: onclick() does not work with iframe. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: As others have stated, we need some code. That said, if you are using jQuery, you could do a `.one()` Also, I don't believe iframes register for click events

Answer (score 1):

This is not very clear question though and it has no tags, but i try..

Assuming that you are using javascript. You can add counter variabel and check it every time you run the event.

```
window.load = function() {
   var count = 0;
   document.getElementById('div_or_iframe').onclick = function() {
      if(count == 0) { // check if counter is 0
         return true; // continue
         count++; // update counter by +1
      }
      else { // if counter is 0 > clicking anything doesn't work
         return false; // prevent action
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear but Im new at scripting.

So,you're saying that I should use this code inside the div or outside it,and what do you mean by 'add counter variabel' ?
Thank you.

Comment: This is why it's always best to post what you're working on.. @user3199188

Comment: Im just trying to make an iframe clickable only once,that's it.It's a new 'project' of mine that im working on.

Comment: @user3199188, you put this code inside `<script>` tags in your page's `head` tag. Counter variable means, that it always updates by +1 when the event is completed(in this case that `if` part). Its variable that keeps count of number of events ran.

Comment: Thank you for your help,but im trying to make it clickable only once,not count the clicks,sorry if Im making no sense but I feel confused.\

Comment: You need to count the clicks to know how many times it has been clicked! If more than 1, then run some other code, like `return false` to stop any action from occurring.....

Comment: It is clickable only once, the counter is just for it. The script checks, if there is counts > 0 and gets part of code to evaluate.

Comment: So,it's kind of like this : 
 if(count == 1) { 
         return false;

Answer (score 0):

I think that @aksu's answer is much easier, but I got it to work with classes and jquery.  This will allow you to have several elements on your page be clickable only once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function someFunction(obj) {
            if ($(obj).hasClass("clickable")) {
                // perform the code you want
                alert("Function will be performed");
                // make not clickable
                $(obj).removeClass("clickable");
            } else {
                alert("Already Clicked");
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clickable" onclick="someFunction(this)">CLICK HERE</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did't know about .one() until after I posted.  Thanks mituw16 very useful!  http://api.jquery.com/one/